# getting wordpress logged user id

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the current user id from an application outside wordpress on the same domain inside a subfolder using:

```
require_once('../wp-config.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$userid = $current_user->ID;
```

but the result is always 0

I'm sure the application connects successfully to the wordpress core because I can show any user information using a code like this

```
echo get_usermeta(8,'last_name');
// echoes 'John'
```

can anyone help me with this?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using the members v. 0.2.4 plugin on my wordpress site.

thanks!

Comment: if you do print_r(current_user); what is the output?

Comment: you mean print_r($current_user) ?

WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => )

Comment: Yes. So that is returning the WP_user object. Are you logged in to WordPress admin area ?

Comment: I tried with your code and it is returning me WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [user_login] => admin [user_pass] => when I am logged in and WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => ) when I am logged out. Are you sure you are logged in?

Comment: there is no change on the output. It returns the same when I'm logged as the admin and when I am logged out.

Comment: I tried the same thing. Tried calling the same you did in my other application and it worked well

Answer (score 1):

You can try session. Find what is in session and then get details from database manually using session details. Simply you need to create some mysql queries.